# separating ZMQ socket from express app.js with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, zeromq

I'm coding an Express app that should collect some data sent from a remote machine via ZMQ and update a MongoDB database with the received information.

The updates are sent every 5 minutes and the encoded JSON weights less than 1 KB. Nevertheless I noticed that when app.js is parsing the JSON and writing to the database, the client requests run slowlier.

Shall I put the ZMQ socket code in the app.js (OPTION A), or shall I just use a separate file (OPTION B)? In the case of option B i could do a bash crone to avoid heavy CPU active waits (as updates come every 5 minutes).[image: representation of the options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two part answer:

**You can, and maybe should, separate your ZMQ message processing out from your Express App**

These are two functionally separate actions, there's no reason they need to be in the same process, they don't need to access each other, so there's no harm and could be a benefit in making those separate processes. Whether it's the right choice for you is application dependent.

**There's no reason processing a 1kb json structure once every 5 minutes should noticeably impact performance**

... ***unless*** your volume of client requests is quite high. It *should* only introduce a couple milliseconds of delay, at worst, which under normal workloads should only impact a single request to a degree that would never be noticed by humans. If your request concurrency is high, then that delay can create a slight domino effect that affects multiple requests.  Otherwise, you should consider whether your architecture has some inefficiencies that could be fixed to solve the problem.

Comment: it is what I guessed in the first place. But I do not know much about how JavaScript is actually implemented and I thought that a single file might launch several processes. Thank you!